# Number format with Locale.getDefault() not giving expected result

Tags: locale, default, number-formatting

I have this code:

```
public double stringToDouble(String s) {

       NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());

    try {

        return nf.parse(s).doubleValue();
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

Its working fine but with some values like 60.0 it gives 600.0 and I dont know why, with 60 it gives 60.0

Any suggestions? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the answer is using this code:

```
public double stringToDouble(String s) {

       NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    nf.setGroupingUsed(false);
    ParsePosition parsePosition = new ParsePosition(0);
    Number n = nf.parse(s, parsePosition);
    if (n == null || parsePosition.getErrorIndex() >= 0 || parsePosition.getIndex() < s.length())
    {
      /* not a valid number */
    }
    return n.doubleValue();
}
```

use this instead of Double.parseDouble();

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the default locale on your machine(JVM) is  interpreting the dot as a grouping character (3 digit grouping like 1.000.000,00) and most probably the decimal separator is the comma character.

I run your code on my machine with default UK locales
and for

`System.out.println(stringToDouble("60.0"));`
`System.out.println(stringToDouble("60"));`
`System.out.println(stringToDouble("60,0"));`

it prints:
`60.0`  and 
`60.0`  and 
`600.0`

For portability don't set default but specific locales.